# Swift Segue Exception

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have a problem with the Segue. All segues have an identifier.

I change from one view to the other by writing this:

```
self.performSegue (withIdentifier: "ready", sender: self)
```

This would work only if I open the app 5-10 times (always different) does the app crash with the following error message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<MyApp.4ViewController: 0x1180c7000>) has no segue with identifier' select ''
```

I do not understand why it does not work. The Segue with the identifier "select" is only between VC 1 and 3 but the Segue between VC 3 and Tabbar Controller (VC 4) has the identifier "ready".

```
 func readyToGo()  {
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(check, forKeyPath: "go")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ready", sender: self)
}
```

[image: Storyboard screen capture]

Thank you very much

Comment: did you call self.performSegue (withIdentifier: "select", sender: self) from VC4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your log you perform a segue at VC named `4ViewController` with identifier `select` check your code , despite you say it's between 1 & 3 , check if make the segue back from vc4 to vc1 , may in `viewDidAppear` or when VC 4 overrided methods

Comment: I added a picture. Have checked all the Segue identifier. They Are correct

Comment: can you attach where exactly you run any performSegue with name **select**

Comment: Oh my God!!! You were right! I had one more mistake in my code! Many many thanks! Shame on my head.